# What does the phrase "rival camps from which to compete for resources" mean

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following sentence is quoted from K. Ishiguro's Nobel Lecture. What does the phrase "rival camps from which to compete bitterly for resources or power" mean?  What is the subject of the verb "compete"?

> For the moment we seem to lack any progressive cause to unite us. Instead, even in the wealthy democracies of the West, we're fracturing into rival camps from which to compete bitterly for resources or power.

Answer (score -1):

Notice how the meaning of the sentence becomes clear when we substitute the word *to* (before the word *compete*) with the word *we*:

> For the moment we seem to lack any progressive cause to united us. Instead, even in the wealthy democracies of the West, we're fracturing into rival camps from which we compete bitterly for resources of power.

With that substitution, we can see that the subject of the verb compete is *we*. (I assume you are quoting Ishiguro correctly.)

What Ishiguro is saying is that from their fractured camps, which comprise the wealthy democracies of the West (i.e., *we*) are competing bitterly for resources of power (instead of *sharing* the resources of power, a situation which Ishiguro finds preferable).

Comment: Uh, _compete_ is an infinitive and has no subject here, though infinitives can have subjects. You've simply changed the infinitive to a finite form agreeing with the pronoun you've supplied.

Comment: I repeat: the infinitive  _compete_ has no subject, as in _We want her to drive us to the airport_. You have paraphrased, recasting the inf. clause into a relative, which _does_ have a subject and a _finite_ verb. That does not make _we_ the subj. of the inf., which is never in subject case anyway.

Comment: I agree with rhetorician. In the sensence " We want her to drive us to the airport', I think 'her' is the subject of the verb 'drive' .  The sentence is derived  from the base sentence' We want [ she drives us to the airport].

Comment: It occurrs to me that KarlG uses the word 'subject' differently from I do.